# How to get new updated value from service without subscribing multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service in angular which has a method which returns details when I subscribe to it, but to get new values I have to subscribe it every time and I think it's not ideal.

The service method looks like,

**details.service.ts**

```
getDetails(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http
      .post<any>('baseUrl/detail', { id });
}
```

The component looks like,

**list.component.ts**

```
getDetails() {
    this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(
      (detail) => {
        // logic here...
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

For getting updated details I have to call `getDetails()` every time which leads to multiple subscription. I want to avoid subscribing multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a valid reason for you to call service in a function like this (refreshing data maybe).

Therefore, I would suggest you pipe `take(1)` for `this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id)`. In the subscription, you can bind the result back to your component model.

`take(1)` would take care unsubscription immediately after the service succeeds so you don't have to worry about multiple trailing subscriptions.

Example:

```
public details: any;
getDetails() {
    this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
      (detail) => {
        // logic here...
        this.details = detail;
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yeah it is helpful but it is still causing memory leaks when user navigates to another component i.e., the subscriptions are still active when on another component. I want all the subscription to complete when user navigates to another component.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, so you are saying if the api being called and user navigates to another component, then you would have memory leak?

If that's the case, you can improve with this combo: in ngOnDestroy, have a subject destroy$ to emit a value. Inside getDetails, within the pipe, add takeUntil(this.destroy$).

Basically it will make sure all observables complete when you navigate to another component.

Answer (score -1):

[`ngOnInit()`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) is your place to perform one-time initialisation functions.

You can call all your subscription code from this place.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your subscription inside constructor or ngOnit to avoid this.

```
constructor() { 
this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(
          (detail) => {
            // logic here...
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        );
}
or 
ngOnInit() {
this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(
              (detail) => {
                // logic here...
              },
              err => console.log(err)
            );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

call `getDetails` function from `ngOnInit()`. it'll execute only one time.

check angular [lifecycle-hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.getDetails(); // one time initialize
}

getDetails() {
    this._detailsService.getDetails(this.id).subscribe(
      (detail) => {
        // logic here...
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: But I have to call `getDetails()` multiple times to get updated details. Calling in `ngOnInit()` only doesn't help.

Comment: on initialize if you want to call, call inside ngOnIni otherwise, you can call `getDetails` from HTML or some event.